# SQL Server / Web Server language independent DATE/CURRENCY/DECIMAL query with ASP.NET

Tags: sql-server, date, locale, iso

We had all our sites hosted on a Win 2003 server (italian) and DBs on SQL Server 2005 (italian).

Now we transfered everything to another host where they have Win 2008 (english us) and SQL Server 2008 (english us).

All the dates are now `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Luckily I developed the asp code using some functions that passed ISO format for dates both in the stored procedure and dynamic queries (like `yyyymmdd`).

And retrieving them we parsed the dates through other asp functions before display so everything went ok.

Now we are switching to asp.net so since it seems to have great culture support I was wondering if it has some built in functions for this purpose, to read/pass/format/insert dates with SQL Server so that they are completely independent from the Win server locale and the SQL Server language, or do we have to code those functions ourselves as we did with classic asp?

Also there may be issues with decimal and currency as well, treating the "," or "." for decimal separation. I'm not aware if passing decimal with "." to SQL Server (and using inside queries and stored procedures) is always correct or there may be some issues like for dates.

Any hint on those subject?

Comment: Why are you passing strings? Use parameterized queries and stored procedures. Then, you pass dates as dates, and the format doesn't matter.

Comment: You mean that if in ASP.NET I pass dates and currency as parameters I don't need to use the ISO format?
Let's say I have italian language on the webserver and the date format is ddmmyyyy and have english-us in sql server wich is mmddyyyy passing date as parameter wouldn't pose an issue? Also when I read decimal numbers (or currency) from a form, how should I treat it before passing to SQL? If the user inserts 123,33 (with the comma as decimal separator) should I pass this as parameter or converto to 123.33 before passing? Also is the "." always locale indipendent for SQL Server?

Comment: Your parameter would be of type DateTime, so you'd pass something like `DateTime.Now`, or `new DateTime(yyyy,mm,dd)`. It's binary.

Comment: Using new DateTime(yyyy,mm,dd) would solve user inserted date issues. Thanks! Do you know something about decimals and currency as well? How should we treat user inserted decimal (wich may contain both . or , based on culture) and safely insert in SQL Server without worrying of its language setting? Does it always use the . for decimals even for languages that expect , ? Do you think that passing those as paramters with the correct types would automatically solve any issue? On ASP.NET I guess we should implement a check based on culture in any case before inserting in a decimal type I guess.

Comment: Same exact thing. The data specified as parameters is binary, not a string representation.

Comment: Ok thanks John still have to do some testing with decimal for the step of retrieving it from a form field and inserting in the .net type before sending to SQL Server but thanks for your suggestions, this will speed up things!